# Метод wall.getById не отображает фото

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

```
<?php
$records_json=file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getById?posts=-89869543_17797&extended=0&v=5.60");
$records=json_decode($records_json, true);

foreach($records['response'] as $record) {
    echo "<li id='".$record['id']."'>".$record['text']."";
    if (isset($record['attachment']['photo']['src_big']))
    echo "<p><img src='".$record['response'][0]['photo_604']."'></p>";
    echo "</li>";
}
?>
```

в результате показывает только текст, а фото не выводит (как сделать вывод всех 7 фото с записи )
помогите пожалуйста с выводом фото, заранее благодарен

Comment: Нам пару дампов данных пожалуйста, поможет вам наш официант `print_r($records_json)`.

Comment: дамп скинул, смотрите ниже

Comment: Не вижу я дампа.